# Adjunction between a comonad and a monad

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, monads

Although this looks like elementary, I have trouble understanding the proof of Theorem 3.1 at [page 7 of this paper](https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/dao7/drafts/monad-or-comonad-orchard11-draft.pdf#page=7). As hypotheses we are given a comonad $D$, a monad $T$ and an adjunction $D \dashv T$. But then in the course of the proof (at the top of page 8), the author constructs the monad $T$ from the comonad $D$. Why is the constructed monad identical to the one in hypotheses?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105024/discussion-on-question-by-bob-adjunction-between-a-comonad-and-a-monad).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Seems to me that this question should have a straightfoward answer not requiring an extended discussion.

Comment: @GregoryGrant Indeed, I was indeed expecting a straightforward answer but it never came. Since 3 people have already voted for closing this question (due to "Needs details or clarity"), and the only attempt at an answer does not answer this question (see the Edit section at the end of the proposed answer), I would rather delete it but I am not allowed to do so.

Comment: @Bob sorry you're message was attacked as inappropriate, I don't think it was I voted to keep it open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all follows from the calculus of mates, which gives a natural bijection between natural transformations $\alpha:F\to F'$ between left adjoints and natural transformations $G'\to G$ between their right adjoints. Specifically, the mate $\bar{\alpha}$ is defined as the composite $$G'\stackrel{\eta_{G'}}{\to}GFG'\stackrel{G\alpha G'}{\to}GF'G'\stackrel{G\varepsilon'}{\to}G$$
where $\eta$ is the unit of $F\vdash G$ and $\varepsilon'$ is the counit of $F'\vdash G'$.

More abstractly, the mate construction may be interpreted as giving an equivalence between the 2-categories $\mathbf{Cat}_{\mathrm{Radj}}$ and $\mathbf{Cat}_{\mathrm{Ladj}}^{\mathrm{op,co}}$ of categories with right adjoint functors and natural transformations, respectively, of left adjoint functors and natural transformations with both 1- and 2-morphisms reversed.

Now a monad in a 2-category $\mathcal K$ is equivalently a monad in $\mathcal K^{\mathrm{op}}$ (a monoid in a monoidal category remains a monoid when the monoidal product is reversed) and a comonad in $\mathcal K^{\mathrm{co}}$ (a monoid in a monoidal category is a comonoid in the opposite monoidal category.)

Thus a monad $(T,\mu,\eta)$ on a category $\mathcal C$ uniquely determines a comonad structure $(U,\bar\mu,\bar\eta)$ on any left or right adjoint to $T$, *subject to* the condition that the comonad structure should be related to the monad structure via the calculus of mates.

**EDIT:** I see I missed the point of the question, which is whether there is a unique comonad structure on the left or right adjoint of a monad. There is no reason for this at all. The paper you link should assume that the given comonad is adjoint to the given monad *and* that the comonad structure is given via mates as above. An easy example of a functor with a *right* adjoint and multiple monad structures is $M\times(-)$, for any set $M$ admitting multiple monoid structures. For a functor with a right adjoint and multiple comonad structures, consider a vector space $V$ with multiple coalgebra structures. This puts multiple comonad structures on the endofunctor $V\otimes (-)$ of vector spaces, which is a left adjoint.

Comment: I guess the answer I was seeking is all in the first paragraph. Incidentally, are mates related to [morphisms between adjunctions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2852012/defining-category-of-adjunctions)?

Comment: @Bob Absolutely, see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-category+of+adjunctions

Comment: If you reverse left and right in the definition of mate, do you get a "co-mate"?

Comment: @Bob Usually one just uses the same word either way, as the "co-mate" of the mate recovers the original natural transformation.

Comment: You write that it is a *natural* bijection. Can you spell out the naturality condition?

Comment: But still, there is a problem in the paper: we fix the monad and comonad structures on $T$ and $U$. So ok, from the adjunction between $T$ and $U$, we can transfer the monad structure from $T$ to a comonad structure on $U$ in such a way that the Kleisli and coKleisli categories are isomorphic. But I imagine it is not true that this always give the initial comonad structure on $U$ (in other words, this comonad structure is not unique). This is how I read the question.

Comment: @Bob Maybe you already know the notation of string diagrams ([*Category Theory Using String Diagrams*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.7220))? It is a lot easier than the notation used in the paper.

Comment: @Idéophage That is exactly what I thought but, according to this answer "*this all follows from the calculus of mates*". Are you implying that this answer is wrong?

Comment: @Idéophage I know about string diagrams. And then?

Comment: @Bob There is nothing wrong in this answer but it does not answer your question.

Comment: @Idéophage Well, the first sentence of this answer says that it answers my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105048/discussion-between-ideophage-and-bob).

Comment: @Bob I have edited.

Comment: So you're saying that the paper is wrong?

Comment: @Bob Yes, the theorem is incorrect as stated. There is a similar-sounding theorem which is true, as I explained in my answer. In any case there’s nothing verging on novelty in the category theoretic part of the paper; just read the references, unless your main interest is in the computer science.

Comment: @KevinCarlson I was interested in the stated result. But this result is surely not in the references since it is wrong.

Comment: @Bob Yes? But I would think the corrected form would satisfy your needs. It’s unnatural to consider a comonad adjoint to a monad without consistency requirements on the structure transformations.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Take the example of the product comonad and the exponential monad. They form an adjunction. But the theorem by Eilenberg and Moore does not ensure that starting from the exponential monad you get the product comonad (and conversely with the dual theorem). Thus there is no guarantee that the corrected theorem 3.1 is about about the product comonad and the exponential monad. But look at the motivating example just after the proof: It assumes the non-corrected form of Theorem 3.1.

Comment: @Bob Fine, but in fact the product and exponential comonad and monad are adjoint in the strong sense necessary to give the desired isomorphism of (co)Kleisli categories, and the same is true in any example that could conceivably of any serious interest. One just has to check a couple more conditions.

Comment: What do you mean by the "strong sense"? What are those addtional "conditions"?

Comment: @Bob That the structure of the comonad is the mate of the structure of the monad, of course, as we’ve been talking about for several days.

Comment: @KevinCarlson I was unsure because for me it is not obvious that the $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ of the product comonad are the respective mates of the $\eta$ and $\mu$ of the monad.

Comment: @Bob Yes, that’s not immediate, but it’s something to check.

Comment: @KevinCarlson In order to ease the checking, are there some useful commutative diagrams satisfied by mates?

Comment: @Bob What you want to use is the pasting diagrams arising from the definition of mate. Moritz Groth's paper "derivators, pointed derivators, stable derivators" has some nice introduction to the calculus of mates in an appendix, if I recall correctly. Certainly this is true of one of his papers with Ponto and Shulman.

Comment: Your answer was inspiring and I have now a related question that you might find easy to answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4382707